# "Send you" vs "Send to you"

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the two is grammatically correct?

> I will send an email to you.

OR

> I will send you an email.

In corporate organizations, I have seen people using both but am pretty much confused with these.

I was thinking *send you* is right only in a context like this:

> I will send you to my friend's company tomorrow.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Both are correct as the verb "send" can take one "direct object" or two "indirect and dicrect objects".

Comment: Both are correcf, but the singular of "email" is _an email message_. A shorter, more  colloqial expression:  I'll email you tomorrow."

Comment: Somehow, "I'm sending to you a big bouquet of roses" just wouldn't sound right.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVqJC6q1z8U

Comment: @BrianHitchcock We now say that the singular of "email" is "an email" - there is no need for "message".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both versions are perfectly fine.

In the case of

> I will send you an email.

"you" is an indirect object.  It is understood that the subject is not sending "you", but rather sending the email.

Personally the first version,

> I will send an email to you.

sounds a little stilted.

In conversational English, you would probably use email as a verb.

> I will email you.

Comment: +1 - I'd describe these as formal and informal versions of the same statement.